# Sqlite select from two tables and ordery by limit

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT y.M_id,SUM(t.alarm_sum),y.yarn1,AVG(t.yarn1_in),SUM(t.yarn1_alarm)
FROM '111' t, yarn y 
WHERE t.date=date('now') AND y.M_id='111' 
ORDER BY t.row_id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

I want to get the data from 2 table: '111' and yarn, but i only want the last 5 rows of data from '111'.
I ran it but the output is not limited by 5 rows from the '111' table.
What is needed to change?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery e.g.

```sql
select ...
from (select * from '111' order by row_id desc limit 5) t,
     yarn y
[...]
```

However it's not clear to me that this makes any sense, and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve either.

What you're doing here is [a cartesian join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join): functionally the database is going to select all rows of t, all rows of y, create every combination of both (so it's going to create the combination of t's first row with all of y's, t's second row with all of y, ...), then it will filter based on your condition, and finally order and limit.

I'm surprised you're getting anything other than the very last row from t though.

(also calling a column `row_id` seems like a bad idea in sqlite as it'd be easy to confuse [with the database's own `rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)).

Comment: thanks for your help. it works now with your solution. do i need an extra row_id or DB's own rowid can be called instead of row_id

Comment: You probably want your own primary key, I was just noting that `row_id` is a bit risky / confusing and possibly error-prone, not that it's wrong per-se. I wouldn't recommend relying on sqlite's own rowid but thats personal preference.